# Unable to Set AD User DirectReport Property

Tags: powershell

### Scenario

In AD, I have a user named `Nykkie`, who has a direct report property called `Rebecca`.
[image]

#### My attempt 1

```
get-aduser NykkieG | Set-ADUser -directreports jamesc
```

I tried to replace it with `jamesc` via PowerShell, but getting below error:

**Error**

```
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directreports'.
At line:1 char:39
get-aduser NykkieG | Set-ADUser -directreports jamesc
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

#### My attempt 2

```
get-aduser NykkieG | Set-ADUser -manager jamesc
```

While this action didn't result in an error this time, it still didn't modify the "direct report" field on the account as required.

Do you have any recommendations or alternative approaches to address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the `-Manager` parameter of `Set-ADUser` command with the `DistinguishedName` property value of the manager account.

Execute the command `Get-ADUser -Identity jamesc` with the `SamAccountName` value to display the `DistinguishedName` value of the specified manager's account.

#### Example `DN` Value

```
DistinguishedName : CN=James Cook,OU=K9 Unit,OU=Police,OU=Dade County,DC=mdcpd,DC=gov
```

Using PowerShell, you can assign the manager's `SamAccountName` to the variable `$uName` to designate that account as the manager of `NykkieG` as a quick solution.

### PowerShell

```
$uName = "jamesc";
$mgr = (Get-ADUser -Identity $uName).DistinguishedName;
Get-ADUser NykkieG | Set-ADUser -Manager $mgr;
```

Comment: This will set `NykkieG`'s account `Manager` property to be `jamesc` and that account. When you look at `JamesC`'s account after this change, you will see `Direct reports` listed as including `NykkieG`.  You can have multiple people as a manager that direct report to you, but each account can only have one Manager in AD. I wanted to mention that in case you are looking or understand the fields in reverse just in case or if any of this is applicable. I already wrote an answer so I'll  leave it for now since it may help.

Comment: So you have ***The Manager Of*** and ***Who is your Manager***. You can just set everyone's manager accordingly and be all set. Also note this in case mixing `Rebecca` and `JamesC` in the commands run and understanding which fields are set to which values where—may be the confusion too...  @ppau2004